# How do i use a regular for loop in a data source?

Tags: terraform

I'm looking at a working example of something like this with for_each (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html):

```
data "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids
  id       = each.value
}
```

I want to do the same thing but I have a regular list not a list of maps. This throws an error

```
data "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetworks" {
  for_each = data.google_compute_network.vpc.subnetworks_self_links
  self_link       = each.value
}

The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument
must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list
of string.
```

So I converted it to a set:

```
data "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetworks" {
  for_each = toset(data.google_compute_network.vpc.subnetworks_self_links)
  self_link       = each.value
}
```

And it works but this is very confusing and seems like I'm doing it wrong. How can I use the regular "for" loop here instead?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids` is *not* a list of IDs rather it's a `set` of IDs. This is why it's working in the first example you've given.

`for_each` requires a `set` or a `map` because it uses the values in the `set` or keys in the `map` to uniquely identify the resources that are created. In terraform, as in most other languages `set`s cannot have repeated elements and `maps` must have unique keys.

If `for_each` accepted a list, it would then have to deal with cases like `["a", "a"]` which would not serve to uniquely identify the produced resources.